# Where can I find examples of visual competitor reviews for a brand designers?

Tags: competitions, branding

I'm teaching graphic design and would like to show my students an example of a competitor review presentation (i.e. a presentation showing how competitors in the same industry present their brand)

Where can I find an examples of this type of presentation?

I've searched throughout the web, Googling, searching SLideShare, using different terms like brand benchmarking, brand competitor analysis etc.- All in vain.
Many thanks.

Comment: Why not make some of your own?

Comment: This could be a good research project for the students to do as an assignment.

Answer (score 1):

A good competitive market or trend analysis will be the result of lots of work by very skilled people and forms part of the company in question's IP and USP. I've worked for a few companies that performed this sort of work and we never shared any of it online. The results are too valuable.

I would suggest that the closest thing that you will find to this would be by hunting sites such as Pinterest for relevant collections of images.

Answer (score 0):

My two cents.

How would you actually do it?

The question is too board, because there are brands on consumer products or brands that has almost no contact to an end user.

There are TV campaigns, retail store degustations, etc. So you need to have specific objectives to present them.

Comment: When creating a competitor review, you need to decide what topics would bring most value to your client. As an example, I did one for a charity. I wanted to show that the visual elements & tone of voice of the charity's brand were letting it down. So I made a presentation touching on the various elements of the charity's key branding elements that needed improving (eg. logo, use of colour, imagery, tone of voice etc.), I also did research the competitors' branding components and drew comparison between them. Of course, other competitor reviews may have a different focus.